# command "openstack image create" not available

Tags: debian, openstack, debian-jessie, openstack-glance

Using a deb8 environment to test openstack following this guide: http://docs.openstack.org/draft/install-guide-debian/overview.html

Now, so far so good, but when I'm working on the image service, i try to verify the operation and test to create and image;

```
control@controller:~/openstackrc$ openstack image create \
--file ../images/cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-disk.img --disk-format qcow2 \
--container-format bare --public cirros
```

the terminal return with;

ERROR: openstack Invalid command '--file'

if i use --help for the openstack command i get;

```
control@controller:~/openstackrc$ openstack --help | grep image
[--os-image-api-version <image-api-version>]
--os-image-api-version <image-api-version>
image delete Delete an image
image list List available images
image save Save an image locally
image show Show image details
server image create Create a new disk image from a running server
```

---

I guess it has something to do with with versions so i'll include the tools' version numbers;

```
control@controller:~/openstackrc$ openstack --version
openstack 0.4.0
control@controller:~/openstackrc$ glance-api --version
2014.1.3
```

i download the packages through the debian jessie backport repo's.

Literaly couldn't find anything elsewhere, so any help is much appreciated!

Best!

Comment: I think you still need to use the python glance client, the openstack common client is new and certainly not all commands are available yet.

Comment: few weeks later and retrying by using mitaka backports from somewhere I was able to overcome this obstacle :). No need to use the glance client anymore, but thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started over and got past this. Basically by reinstalling the packages bare metal, abandoning the lxc setup.

Works fine now.